# GIT Server integrado com Redmine

Tags: git, commit, redmine

Eu possuo um servidor de git integrado com redmine, ele está configurado certo e está sendo utilizado por várias pessoas, porém quando o comentário do commit possui aspas duplas (") ele da não sincronizado.
Eu utilizo um script, abaixo a parte referente ao cometário:

```
function redmine_update_issue {
    redmine_host=$(git config redmine.host)
    redmine_apikey=$(git config $GL_USER.apikey)
    content="{\"issue\":{\"notes\":\"\nRealizado commit no GIT, detalhes:\n\n-Mensagem de Commit:\n $2\"}}"

    debug "funcao redmine_update_issue - content=$content - redmine_apikey=$redmine_apikey - redmine_host/1=$redmine_host/$1"
    curl --silent -k -H "Contet-Type: application/json" -X PUT --data "$contet" -H "X-Redmine-API-Key: $redmine_apikey" "$redmine_host/$1" }
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia?

Desde já obrigado!

Comment: `$2` provavelmente esta incluindo aspas duplas não escapadas e  content  está corrompido (tente dar um `echo` na saída de content para confirmar). A solução é substituir `"` por `\"` em `$2` no seu script.